# Stunted Functionality of html5 <audio> tag in mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile, audio, browser

While testing the HTML audio tag, I came across two problems with mobile browsers.  First, the "autoplay" attribute does not always function, so that the user needs to touch the "start" button on the screen.  Second, a 1:09 recording, cuts off at about one minute with some browsers, but plays to completion with others.  An example of the first problem is that autoplay works as it should using the Google Chrome browser on my desktop, but not on my Android (HTC EVO) mobile phone.  An example of the second problem is that the mobile Chrome browser plays the audio file to completion on my phone, but the default browser that came with my phone cuts off about 8 seconds prematurely.  The autoplay feature, however, works as it should on the "default" browser.

Are these problems caused by reduced functionality and memory when going from a desk or laptop environment to a smartphone environment?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Android, but iOS has well-known limitations on HTML5 audio and video. Apple claims they are designed to save data charges, even though they apply even when you are on WiFi, or the assets are local as in an e-book.

The limitations include no preloading until some user interaction occurs, no looping, no inline replay on iPhone, no change of playback rate, no playing backwards, no volume control, etc. etc. See http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/ for a good summary.